# Returning promise but still .then is undefined in angular jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to replace actual service with mock service while writing Unit test cases for controller. What I'm trying to achieve is using `.and.callFake` function of jasmine but its not working as expected.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/619frt3L/4/)

```
spyOn(mockTestService,'getData').and.callFake(function() {
     console.log("log from mock service");
     deferred.resolve({data : "mockRes"});
     return deferred.promise;
});
```

I want to return mock data for one of my service call and verify success call back function of controller.

Comment: Are you sure `deferred.resolve` returns nothing?

Comment: Simpler ~ `return $q.when({data: 'mockRes'});`

Comment: Also, you need to move your spy creation to **before** creating the controller as it tries to use the `testService` immediately. Also also, you've included Jasmine 1.3 but are using 2.x syntax

Comment: Here it is all fixed up for you ~ http://jsfiddle.net/619frt3L/5/

Comment: Thanks Phill. Got your point. I tried to change version here http://jsfiddle.net/619frt3L/6/ but its throwing error!!